# Microsoft Mouse Not Detected in Vmware Windows 7 x64 on the mac

Tags: windows-7, usb, vmware, mouse

i hope someone can help with this problem im having, my wireless microsft mouse is not detected in windows 7 in vmware running on a mac.
i have installed the intellipoint driver version 8, and this is where it tells me it is not dectected, nor does the usb device show up in the usb device list under vmwares settings of that machine.
so i cannot allocate the usb device to to vmware. the mouse works, but only the left, right and scrolling functions operate.
the back forward and more importantly middle mouse button click do not work at all. this is quite problomatic considering i use 3Ds Max

i understand that this is because it sees the mouse as the host mouse, but this is of no use to me, i need the functionality of the middle mouse button.
Can anyone assist?